# Создание методов под определенный конструктор

Tags: c#

Есть, к примеру, класс:

```
public class LiveClient
{
    private HttpClient httpClient;

    private readonly string publicKey;
    private readonly string secretKey;

    private const string baseAddress = "https://my.domain";

    public LiveClient()
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress) };
    }

    public LiveClient(string publicKey, string secretKey)
    {
        this.publicKey = publicKey;
        this.secretKey = secretKey;

        httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress) };
    }

    public void MyWithOutParamConstructorMethod()
    {
        //работает с конструктором без параметров
    }

    public void MyParamconstructorMethod()
    {
        //работает с параметризированным конструктором
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при создании клиента через конструктор без параметров, не было доступа к методу который работает лишь через клиент созданный параметризированным конструктором? А с помощью клиента, созданного параметризированным конструктором был доступ ко всем методам в том числе и `MyWithOutParamConstructorMethod()`?

Comment: Без наследования - никак. Есть класс и у него либо публичный, либо приватный метод. Как программа вообще должна понять, что сейчас перед вами экземпляр, созданный без параметров? И как она должна реагировать, если вы попробуете запустить метод, доступный только в классе с параметрами?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наследованием.

```
public class LiveClient
{
  private const string baseAddress = "https://my.domain";

  protected HttpClient httpClient { get; private set; }

  public LiveClient()
  {
    httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress) };
  }

  public void MyWithOutParamConstructorMethod()
  {
    //работает с консруктором без параметров
  }
}

public class LiveClient_WithParams:LiveClient
{
  private readonly string publicKey;
  private readonly string secretKey;

  public LiveClient_WithParams(string publicKey, string secretKey) : base()
  {
    this.publicKey = publicKey;
    this.secretKey = secretKey;
  }

  public void MyParamconstructorMethod()
  {
    //работает с параметризированным  консруктором
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы планируете работать с объектом, как с разными объектами, в зависимости от того, как он был создан, возможно, вам подойдет фокус с 2 интерфейсами. Например

```
public interface IWithParamConstructorMethod
{
    void MyWithOutParamConstructorMethod();
}

public interface IParamconstructorMethod
{
    void MyParamconstructorMethod();
}
```

Сам объект

```
public class LiveClient: IWithParamConstructorMethod, IParamconstructorMethod
{
    private HttpClient httpClient;

    private readonly string publicKey;
    private readonly string secretKey;

    private const string baseAddress = "https://my.domain";

    private LiveClient()
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress) };
    }

    private LiveClient(string publicKey, string secretKey)
    {
        this.publicKey = publicKey;
        this.secretKey = secretKey;

        httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress) };
    }

    public void MyWithOutParamConstructorMethod()
    {
        //работает с конструктором без параметров
    }

    public void MyParamconstructorMethod()
    {
        //работает с параметризированным конструктором
    }

    public static IWithParamConstructorMethod CreateLiveClient(string publicKey, string secretKey)
    {
        return new LiveClient(publicKey, secretKey);        
    }

    public static IParamconstructorMethod CreateLiveClient()
    {
        return new LiveClient();
    }
}
```

Ну и создавайте его теперь как хотите

```
 LiveClient.CreateLiveClient(..)
```

Нужная перегрузка вернет нужный интерфейс.

Answer (score -1):

Полагаясь на ваши предложения, сделал вот так:

```
public class LiveClient
    {
        protected HttpClient httpClient;

        private const string baseAddress = "https://api.livecoin.net";

        public LiveClient()
        {
            httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress) };
        }
}
```

Класс наледник:

```
public class LiveClientPrivate :LiveClient
    {
        private static LiveClientPrivate instance;
        private static object syncRoot = new Object();

        private readonly string publicKey;
        private readonly string secretKey;

        protected LiveClientPrivate(string publicKey, string secretKey):base()
        {
            this.publicKey = publicKey;
            this.secretKey = secretKey;
        }

        public static LiveClientPrivate Set (string pubKiy, string secKey)
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new LiveClientPrivate(pubKiy, secKey);
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Вызов с парамерами:

`LiveClient liveClient = new LiveClientPrivate.Set("publicKey", "secretKey")`